# Design patterns - How to enforce object attributes only in some situations (Builder pattern, Dependency Injection)

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, builder

I am in a very particular situation with one of the classes I'm coding. I have this class called `User` that looks like this:

```
public class User {
    private long id; // + getters and setters
    private boolean isDeletable; // + getters and setters
    private String name; // + getters and setters
    private String password; // + getters and setters
    private String email; // + getters and setters
    private String authenticationRealm; // + getters and setters
    private String displayName; // + getters and setters
    private Date deletedDate; // + getters and setters
}
```

Within my code there are several situations where I just need an empty object of the type `User` and therefore just build it using the default constructor: `new User()`.

However, I have another class called `CreateUserRequest` which models a REST request to create the user in a server. The **minimum** payload must contain the `name`, `password`, `email`, and `authenticationRealm` attributes sent in JSON format.

Right now I am handling this by checking for these parameters in the constructor of the request:

```
public CreateUserRequest(User user) {
    if(user.getName() == null || user.getPassword() == null || user.getEmail() == null || user.getAuthenticationRealm() == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Not enough attributes in User object. Minimum: name, password, e-mail and authentication realm.");
}
```

This is working OK but something is itchy... I would like to enforce this in a safer way, so that the code would enforce the attributes to be populated with no possibility of an exception being thrown.

I feel like there must be a better way to do this with a design pattern. I thought of creating a `UserRequestBuilder` class, but that would also possibly imply throwing an exception in the `build()` method (otherwise, is there a way I can guarantee that the attributes are populated before `build()`?). Dependency injection also sounds like a possibility, but I'm not sure how I would put it in place in this particular example...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a different object, a CreateUser object perhaps that has a constructor and validates the supplied values.  Any reason they have to be the based on the same class since they are performing two different tasks?

Comment: My immediate thoughts would be add a new isValidUserRequest() method on the User class. Thinking being that the User class should decide itself if it is valid or not for use in request.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @dbugger. Yes - several REST calls either produce or consume JSON objects with the very same attributes of the `User` class (i.e. the User class represents a remote entity). The classes aren't really performing different tasks. The `CreateUserRequest` class builds a REST call that passes a `User` object in its payload in JSON format.

Comment: @LawrenceTierney thanks for the comment. It makes sense. However I would be left with the same problem - what if `isValidUserRequest()` returns false? I still need to treat it somehow. Ideally I would like a way that the user request could only be created (or _built_) if all the attributes are there.

Comment: They can implement the same abstraction then, IUser or UserBase, so they look alike on the outside, but have different goodies on the inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about making your REST services operate on a User[DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)? (Off course, the UserDTO could be replaced with a subclass of User).

You could annotate the fields, setters or constructor parameters on the UserDTO with @NonNull and have the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) issue compiler warnings when passing null values instead of name password, email etc to the UserDTO.

Using a framework like [Mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/), mapping between the REST services DTOs and the backend objects is very easy:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    public static final UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDTO map(User user);

    User map(UserDTO userDTO);
}
```

Above code will upon compilation generate a UserMapper implementation, with autogenerated code for the specified methods ( - and the autogenerated code simply pairs similarly named getters and setters. You could do this yourself, but with many DTOs/Entities is becomes time consuming and boring).

In the DTOs you could exclude all those fields you do not want to expose.

Ps. My own usage of above mentioned is this: I am creating a REST server based on Jersey, i.e. the reference implementation of JAX-RS. This project, call it A, only knows about the DTOs. The REST methods calls into another project B, which retrieves the objects from database, and maps them to the corresponding DTO, which is then returned to project A. Part of the reason for this pattern is that the entities of project B for historical reasons are cluttered with methods/functionality, which should not be exposed to project A. As for the sanity checks (JSON to DTO), jersey supports Bean Validation, which is to say, that the framework will validate each rest resource's input beans if they are annotated with @Valid. 
It is also possible to create your own custom annotations, which have a ConstraintValidator defined. The bean validation framework will check these constraints on the annotated jersey REST method parameters.
See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13690

Comment: Very interesting approach, @Hervian. I will try it out and mark it as an answer if it works. Thank you.

Comment: I followed a very similar approach and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up across a similar problem , I came up with the solution of adding a Custombuilder with constructor having arguments. So it ensures that i am ensuring that client(user) has to provide those credentials for building that object

```
    class UserRequestBuilder{
          public UserRequestBuilder(String name,String password,String email,String authenticationRealm){
// set values here
}
}
```